# How can I hide last two rows of a login page?

Tags: iphone, xcode, tableview

I'm trying to create a similar login/register view as the Tumblr's iPhone app. 
I want the button to hide the last two rows when clicked, and show them again when clicked again.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you be a little more specific on the question.  I checked the tumblr app login page after signing out and there's just two fields - email and password. I'm unsure what "button" you are referring to and what are the rows you want to hide.

Comment: It's the functionality of the "register/login" button on the top left side of their login page that I wanted to mimic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the button toggle a `BOOL hideLastTwoRows` you have set up in the `tableView` class, and then in your implementation of `UITableViewDataSource`, use it like this:

```
// USE THIS if you don't use sections at all
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(self.hideLastTwoRows)
    {
        return [self numberOfRows]-2; // obviously use the right thing here
    } else {
        return [self numberOfRows];
    }
}

// USE THIS if you do use sections, and the last 2 rows are in the second section
- (NSInteger)numberOfSections
{
    if(self.hideLastTwoRows)
        return 1;
    else
        return 2;
}
```

I'm sure you can find other ways to do this as well. Make sure the button also reloads the tableview using `[tableView reloadData]` or similar reload methods passing in specific index paths.

Comment: Yes, that is perfect. Just needed to change hideLastTwoRows in the if statement.

Comment: I have one more question: is there any way to make this transition animated?

Comment: @liquidpenguins Yes, you can use the ["similar reload methods"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW53) I mentioned. More specifically, `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use following code also

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return [arForData count]-2;

}
```